# If <td> tag is empty (no text)... run jquery script for php list page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a php page that generates a list of stock items and I want to determine if the table td for the stock items are empty so that I can run a jquery script that states that we either have the stock item or not.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("#paperId:empty")) {
        $('#tablebox').append("<h2 class=\"floatclear\">There is stock that matches your search parameters.</h2>");
    } else {
        $("table").hide();
        $('#papernav').hide();
        $('#tablebox').append("<h2 class=\"floatclear\">No Stock is currently available.</h2>");
    }
})
```

I think that I should be running this with every submit but don't know how?

Comment: Here is my current test page for results: http://http://worthhiggins.startlogic.com/fb/prp/searchresults.php

Comment: link doesn't work, is that a live server or local?

Comment: Sorry This one works: http://worthhiggins.startlogic.com/fb/prp/searchresults.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's no `$("#paperId")`  in first place.

When you generate the table, in each record add a class like 'papperID' and then count the length of the elements in the dom.

```
  $(".paperId").length
```

Comment: This is the php code that populates the table:

`<?php do { ?>
  <tr>
    <td id="paperId"><?php echo $row_paperlist['paperid']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_paperlist['brand']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_paperlist['type']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_paperlist['weight']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_paperlist['color']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_paperlist['finish']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_paperlist['size']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_paperlist['quantity']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } while ($row_paperlist = mysql_fetch_assoc($paperlist)); ?>`

Comment: You could just use a child selector as well in your query: $('table>tr').length to count how many rows are in the table.

Comment: <td id="paperId"> change the id to class. There should be just one id per element.